# Proper way to delete record in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I just have a very simple situation where all I need is to delete record using Linq2Entities. I tried to do some research and still can't figure out the right way to do it.

Here's my simple code:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)]
public void DeleteEmployee(Employee z)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
    {
        var x = (from y in ctx.Employees
                 where  y.EmployeeId == z.EmployeeId
                 select y).FirstOrDefault();
         ctx.DeleteObject(x);
         ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
 }

[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public List<Employee> GetAllEmployee()
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
    {
        var x = from y in ctx.Employees
                select y;
        return x.ToList();
    }
}
```

I can delete a particular record if for example I assign **y.EmployeeName == "Harold Javier"** to the Delete method above, but when I assign **y.EmployeeId == z.EmployeeId** to the above code, the delete doesn't work. (Note: EmployeeId is the primary key of the Employee table)

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Any errors? post them if so.

Comment: We can compile the code and it seems okay. But when we use it with the ObjectDataSource (ASP.NET WebForm), the Delete button doesn't work.

Comment: Try `ctx.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(x)` instead of `ctx.DeleteObject(x)`

Comment: The code looks ok. Is there an exception? What happens if you step through in the debugger?

Comment: Using the debugger, please check if the `z` object is properly created, and if its `EmployeeId` actually exists in your database.

Comment: @marcinJuraszek, ctx.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(x) works with Linq2Sql, but not the Linq2Entities...@Phil, Yes, there's an exception....@Flater, Yes, z is properly created and EmployeeId exists in the database...

Comment: What is the exception? Doesn't it give you a clue to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question.

My delete function worked when I did the following:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
    {
        var x = (from y in ctx.Employees
             orderby  y.EmployeeId descending
             select y).FirstOrDefault();
        ctx.Employees.DeleteObject(x);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I know there could be a better approach than this, but it works for me for the mean time.

Answer (score 22):

I think this is better option of delete

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
    {
        var x = (from y in ctx.Employees
             orderby  y.EmployeeId descending
             select y).FirstOrDefault();
        ctx.Employees.Remove(x);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

at my side `DeleteObject` is not working so i use `Remove`

Answer (score 10):

you first need to verify that if a record exists before you actually delete it;

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Delete)]

    public void DeleteEmployee(Employee z)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntity())
        {
            var x = (from y in ctx.Employees
                     where  y.EmployeeId == z.EmployeeId
                     select y).FirstOrDefault();
             if(x!=null)
             {
             ctx.Employees.DeleteObject(x);
             ctx.SaveChanges();
             }
        }
     }
```

Always check for nulls, before you delete something. Because a user may change the Id (at querystring) and try different combinations.

Comment: Thanks, DonNet Dreamer. But still checking for nulls doesn't solve our problem.

Comment: I've always used the Delete function as a POST method (`[HttpPost]`), not a get, which eliminates the need to secure the querystring. Null checks are always good practice, but it's not pertinent to OP's question and also not the best way to secure your application.

Comment: I sometimes get an error with this method, so I switched to setting the state which does not return the error.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer may be outdated...  The DeleteObject method does not seem to exist in the current version of ENtity Framework.  I had to use the Remove method.

```
var delobj = db.mytable.Where(p => p.ServiceLocation == serviceLocationID).SingleOrDefault();
db.myTable.Remove(delobj);
```

Answer (score 6):

@Harold, I know this post is quite old, but I feel it is important to address your original question and answer.  Your solution may have worked in your situation, but there are a couple of problems.

First, your original code was selecting the record to delete based on a passed in parameter.  Your solution is deleting the record with the largest EmployeeId.  That might be what you wish, but not likely.
The second issue is that two database accesses are required to accomplish the delete.  The first is get the entity to delete the second to actually perform the delete.

The following code snippet will eliminate the need to to the read and will delete employee "z".  This should yield the desired result and perform much better.

```
public void DeleteEmployeeId(Employee z)
{
    using (var ctx = new MyEntityContext())  
    {  
        var x = new Employee{ EmployeeId = z.EmployeeId };
        ctx.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Deleted;  
        ctx.SaveChanges();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

```
MyList.RemoveAll(x => x.MyField == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the context is different on each request (var ctx = new MyEntity()). Try using this

```
public static class ObjectContextPerHttpRequest
{
    public static TestCasesModelContainer Context
    {
        get
        {
            string objectContextKey = HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("ObjectContextPerHttpRequest");

            if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(objectContextKey))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(objectContextKey, new TestCasesModelContainer());
            }

            return HttpContext.Current.Items[objectContextKey] as TestCasesModelContainer;
        }
    }
}
```

And delete is like

```
public static void Delete(Testcase tc)
{
    var db = ObjectContextPerHttpRequest.Context;

    db.DeleteObject((from p in db.TestcaseSet
                     where p.Id == tc.Id
                     select p).Single());
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```